# Unloading Storyboard View

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I'm opening a storyboard view using the following:

```
    GroupProximity *proximity = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"groupproximity"];

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:proximity animated:YES];
```

However, when I use the back button on the top bar, it appears that the activity is not stopped.  How do I unload a storyboard view when the back button is pressed?

Comment: What "activity" are you talking about?

Comment: I have an NSTIMER that triggers a command.  The timer keeps functioning even when I "leave" the window.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `viewWillDisappear:`. Here you invalidate the timer, allowing it to go out of existence.

For more info about the special lifetime / memory issues associated with NSTimer, see the discussion in my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_unusual_memory_management_situations

Comment: Thanks.  That should be enough to get me in trouble!

Comment: You're using a repeating NSTimer, which is retained by the runloop. You're in plenty of trouble already! :)

Comment: I should also mention that you might want to read my book's chapter on view controllers. The section on lifetime events is here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_view_controller_lifetime_events